# Issues with if/else statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement

Trying to write a simple calculater in C. I'm stuck in having the program terminated if letter 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D' is not entered, otherwise continue.  Even though I enter a valid character it never proceeds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char letter;
    float num1,num2;
    printf("What operation would you like to perform?\n\tA) Addition\n\tB) Subtraction\n\tC) Multiplication\n\tD) Division\n\n");
    scanf("%c", &letter);

    if (letter != 'A' || letter != 'B' || letter != 'C' || letter != 'D')
      printf("Not a valid operation\n");
        return 1;

    printf("Please enter first number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Please enter second number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    if (letter == 'A' || letter == 'a')
        printf("The sum of %f and %f, is %f\n", num1, num2, num1 + num2);

    else if (letter == 'B' || letter == 'b')
        printf("The difference of %f and %f, is %f\n", num1, num2, num1 - num2);

    else if (letter == 'C' || letter == 'c')
        printf("The product of %f and %f, is %f\n", num1, num2, num1 * num2);

    else if (letter == 'D' || letter == 'd')
        printf("The quoation of %f and %f, is %f\n", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
    else 
        printf("The operation was not valid");
    return 0;

}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have two `'B'` clauses in your if-else ladder.

Comment: Thanks dreamlax. I just corrected that. The problem however still exists.

Comment: You may need to call fflush(stdout); after the printf's that don't include a \n at the end of the string in order to make them show up right away.

Comment: @holasz: Please don't edit your question to correct it for things people tell you in their answers, otherwise the answers make no sense at all when you read them. It's better to ask a new question, or at the minimum add a new section prefaced `"EDIT:"` so the original code is still visible.

Comment: You've got a problem with your `quoation` (which should be a 'quotient' in English), in that the code will never be executed because you copied and pasted and forget to edit the `B` and `b` into `D` and `d`.  We can understand what you intended; compilers won't.

Comment: +1 @JonathanLeffler  Yeah I thought I updated that. The question was then edited and so I think I again ended up with `B` and `b`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (letter != 'A' || letter != 'B' || letter != 'C' || letter != 'D')
  printf("Not a valid operation\n");
    return 1;
```

This part is the problem. Although `return 1;` is indented, it will execute regardless because it is not part of the `if` block. Additionally, you are using the wrong operator, your condition statement reads *"if letter is not A or letter is not B ..."* which is always going to be true because letter cannot be both `A` and `B` at the same time. You need to envelope the two statements and use the `&&` operator instead, like this:

```
if (letter != 'A' && letter != 'B' && letter != 'C' && letter != 'D')
{
    printf("Not a valid operation\n");
    return 1;
}
```

In C, indentation is meaningless to the compiler. If you need to execute multiple statements as a result of a condition, they must be wrapped up into a *compound statement* using `{` and `}`.

Comment: Additionally, if the user types in `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`, then the first `if` block, even after your correction, will reject it.  But your larger point, *always use braces*, is correct.

Comment: You need to replace `||` with `&&`, otherwise the condition is always `true` (letter cannot be equal to more than one char at a time, so even if one of the conditions is false, the other tree are going to be true).

Comment: I updated the post. THe problem is still there. Even surrounding it with brackets. `{..}`

Comment: @holasz look at what dasblinkenlight said and think about how `||` works. The problem will become apparent.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You were right. It was the `&&` instead of `||`. Updated my question. 
@dreamlax, please update your answer and I will mark it as a solution.

Comment: I was working on an edit to expand my answer and correct the `&&`/`||` thing and now I see it was already in the comments!

Comment: Thank you guys. It works perfectly now!  I had just a brainfart about  `&&` and `||`  All sorted now thanks to you

Comment: @dreamlax: Sorry, I mistook you for the original poster anyway, I deleted my comment.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Just at the point to update the post. You are right. I modified it to the complete solution which was given to me. Meanwhile the post was updated. THanks again and have a good time all you ^^

Comment: Is there any way to have a regex as in  `if (letter == '[Aa]')` ..?

Comment: @holasz: use `if ( tolower(letter) == 'a' )` or similar. C has no standard regex support, although C++ now does.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths so that will check for both cases? e.g  `if (tolower(letter) == 'a')` would be equivalent to  `if(toupper(letter) == 'A')` and match both?

Comment: @holasz: It won't actually *check* both cases, but it'll achieve the same end by converting to one of the cases and checking that. And yes, your two examples would achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You check

```
 if (letter != 'A' || letter != 'B' ...)
```

Ok - if letter is 'B', then it is not A, and the program stops testing there and prints your failure condition and returns.

On the other hand, if letter was 'A', it would not be 'B', and so it would fail the second test instead, and fail there.

What you want:

```
if (letter != 'A' && letter != 'B' && letter != 'C' && letter != 'D')
```

Alternately, you could use the C function "strchr" which searches for a character in a string.

```
if (!strchr("ABCDabcd", letter)) // returns NULL, which is false, if no match
{
    printf("Invalid operation");
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (letter != 'A' && letter != 'B' && letter != 'C' && letter != 'D')
...
```